# Is this a bug in boost::range_detail::demote_iterator_traversal_tag of boost::iterator_facade?

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

Following code:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <boost/range/join.hpp>
struct foo {
    typedef int result_type;
    result_type operator ()(int x) { return x; }
};
int main() {
    using boost::adaptors::transformed;
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
    boost::join(a | transformed(foo()), a | transformed(foo()));
    return 0;
}
```

will get a compile error:

```
error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'boost::range_detail::demote_iterator_traversal_tag<IteratorTraversalTag1,IteratorTraversalTag2>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            IteratorTraversalTag1=boost::detail::iterator_category_with_traversal<std::input_iterator_tag,boost::random_access_traversal_tag>,
1>            IteratorTraversalTag2=boost::detail::iterator_category_with_traversal<std::input_iterator_tag,boost::random_access_traversal_tag>
1>        ]
...
```

in VS2008 with boost 1.45.

I dived into the source code of `boost::range_detail::demote_iterator_traversal_tag` and found it doesn't give a consideration about `boost::detail::iterator_category_with_traversal` which is produced by `boost::detail::facade_iterator_category` used by `iterator_facade` to deduce proper iterator category.

The `transform_iterator` is based on `iterator_facade`, so the iterator category of `a | transformed(foo())` is deduced to be `iterator_category_with_traversal<std::input_iterator_tag,boost::random_access_traversal_tag>`, but `demote_iterator_traversal_tag` don't recognize it.

I don't understand why `demote_iterator_traversal_tag` designed like this. Or maybe its just a bug?

Thanks.

Comment: You might also consider placing a similar post on the mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case any future Google users end up here like I did, yes it looks like this was a bug, because it is fixed in at least version 1.54 (probably sooner, I hit the bug using 1.44 and just downloaded the current version).

Answer (score 0):

`IteratorTraversalTag1` and `IteratorTraversalTag2` derive both from `std::input_iterator_tag` and `boost::random_access_traversal_tag`. Thus the `demote_iterator_traversal_tag` should have matched with `BOOST_DEMOTE_TRAVERSAL_TAG( random_access_traversal_tag, random_access_traversal_tag, random_access_traversal_tag )`. The `::type` should have been `random_access_traversal_tag`. This looks really like a bug.